# Sending specific Resultset values via buttons from 1 JSP to another

Tags: jsp, jdbc

Suppose I have an ordinary table in HTML with a few rows and columns. Now I am fetching certain info from database in ResultSet and showing them as table data(`<td>`). Now, I have 2 buttons beside every row in the table named ‘Accept’ and ‘Reject’. It looks something like:

`<tr>
    <td>………Resultset displays values……</td>     Button Accept    Button Reject
    <td>………Resultset displays values…….</td>     Button Accept    Button Reject
</tr>`

Now suppose I am pressing button ‘Accept’ beside the first `<td>`. I want it to work like: On pressing of button ‘Accept’, I want to attach the value of the column displayed by Resultset in its place i.e. value fetched by ResultSet in the place of 1st   `<td>` as an attribute and send it to another JSP; such that in the destination JSP, when I will fetch the value of that attribute, it will display that particular value of ResultSet which had been displayed in the home JSP in the place of first `<td>`. Similarly, when I press the ‘Accept’ button beside the next `<td>`, it will set the value of ResultSet shown in that `<td>` as a request attribute, move to the destination JSP and show me that particular rs value which was displayed in the former JSP in the place of second `<td>`. Same action to be performed on pressing ‘Reject’ button when JSP moves to another JSP carrying with it the particular value of Resultset in that `<td>`. If it's comprehensible, please do help.

Comment: You can't actually have buttons outside of <td>s in a table.

Comment: Then how to meet my need? Please suggest alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's suppose that you're having a row like this one, from what i understand now what you're looking for is to have the row id as attribute in the botton

```
<td>………Resultset displays values……</td><button id=<%=rs.getString("your_id_name")%> name="btn_1">accpet</button>
```

now what you need in you jsp is just to store that id in request object , and by this way you can get it in any jsp page you desire , for example,
after testing on the click on accept btn by this way :

```
<%
if(request.getParameter("btn_1") != null )
{
 request.setAttribute("id" , rs.getString("the_id") );
 response.sendRedirect("destination.jsp");
}
%>
```

once the id is setted & redirected you to a page where you want 
you can get the id "indestination.jsp" by this way !!

```
<% String id = request.getAttribute("the_id") ; 
   out.print("id id "+id); %>
```

and it's the same thing you can perform in the reject button i hope it was helpful .. otherwise show me some examples link or code to be able to help you more.

Comment: I need to insert an HTML button just beside every row displayed by the resultset, on click of which the page navigates. Then how can I use RequestDispatcher object in case when I want the current JSP page to move to another JSP on click of that button?

Comment: so by following what you're demanding i think this could much helpful 
1 st thing you insert a button beside the row like this 
<td><input type='button' value='Go' name='btn_1' /></td> 
and after that you get value of that button & you made a simple test on it like this way 
String op=request.getParameter("btn_1"); 
if(op!=null){
request.sendRedirect('pageYouWantToRedirect.jsp');
}
and that's all use just sendRedirect it will be useful without the requestDispatcher , hope that was helpful

Comment: Yes that could have helped but while redirecting to another JSP I need to send a particular attribute value fetched by resultset to the destination page. So, even if I can fetch the value of the button in Servlet, how to ensure that the attribute value specific to that tuple which the resultset has fetched can be sent?

Comment: @QUEEN i'm still confused about what you are expecting from your code if you could clarify moore about the issues what you have done and what you get and what are you expecting it could be great

Comment: I couldn't comment as it exceeded 800  characters and thus was forbidden. But have edited my question. Please do refer to the changed question.

Comment: I modified your code a bit and successfully got what I wanted! I don't know how to thank you. Please do accept my heartfelt thanks online:) @PacMan

Comment: @QUEEN if it was helpful please mark it as the right answer so other people could see it :) thanks

Comment: WIll definitely do it. Plz tell me how to mark an answer correct in this site?

Comment: @QUEEN just click on the green button at the left of my answer and and made a ^ up vote that's it :)